# MGT PeoplePicker selectionChanged event parameter type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web-parts, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am creating a SPFx web part with React and I am using the [Microsoft Graph Toolkit PeoplePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker). It offers a `selectionChanged` callback. This callback gets passed a parameter of type `Event` (defined in `typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts`)

```
export type PeoplePickerProps = {
    // ....
    selectionChanged?: (e: Event) => void;
}
```

However, according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/mgt-react#usage) I need to access `event.target.selectedPeople`. But `selectedPeople` does not exist as property of `event.target`.

My code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { PeoplePicker, People } from '@microsoft/mgt-react/dist/es6/spfx';

export const EmployeePicker: React.FC = (): React.ReactElement => {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([]);

  const handleSelectionChanged = (event: Event): void => {
    console.log('Selection changed');
    console.log('event', event);
    setPeople(event.target.selectedPeople);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <PeoplePicker selectionChanged={handleSelectionChanged} />
      Selected People:
      <People people={people} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'd like to avoid opting out of the type system. (I guess changing the type of `event` to `any` would work) And rather know how I can access the `event.target.selectedPeople` prop using typescripts type system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *event.details* too. You can read about it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/customize-components/events. For the people picker there will be an array of the currently selected people.

To make it work with typescript you can either use any or do something like event.target["selectedPeople"] or event["details"]. Or you can create a new type like

```
type PeoplePickerEventTarget = EventTarget & {selectedPeople: IDynamicPerson[]};
```

<s>I am not sure what the type of the array is, you can replace any with the correct one or just build your own.</s>

And then in the code you can do something like this

```
<PeoplePicker
  selectionChanged={(e: Event) => {
     const target = e.target as PeoplePickerEventTarget;
        //do something here
  }}
></PeoplePicker>
```

Comment: selectedPeople is an IDynamicPerson[]